# Does a select on a view keep the order by from the view?

Tags: sql, oracle

When view is created including an `ORDER BY` clause, will that order be maintained when using `SELECT * FROM VIEW`?
Or is it necessary to state `SELECT * FROM VIEW ORDER BY` ?

Comment: Are you asking about the Oracle Database or Oracle's Java DB? The question is tagged for Oracle Database, but the docs you reference are for Oracle's Java DB product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need an `order by` on the outer query to guarantee that the rows are returned in the order you want.

If you run a `select * from view` query against the view without a `where` clause, it is likely that the rows would be returned in the order defined in the `order by`.  But that's not something that you should depend on.

Comment: So why would oracle bother specifying ORDER BY on their CREATE VIEW document and ORDER BY document. I get it that it CAN be done, but if it doesnt make a difference then why would it be there in the documentation?  https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj15446.html

Comment: @user3460414 - The documentation you're referencing is not for the Oracle database.  It is for a different database (JavaDB) that happens to be owned by Oracle the corporation.  As to why Oracle would allow you to put an `order by` in a view definition, it's not my favorite feature.  There are times where "it's very likely that rows will be returned in the order you expect" is good enough.  There are times when you want to prevent predicate pushing.  I can't think of a situation where I've been really glad to put an `order by` in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 19 definitely supports writing "create view ... as select ... from ... order by ...". As for why would anyone do it, Oracle may be using this as a hint to return the results sorted as specified, but I'd never recommend writing "order by" in the view definition, because ordering should always be done by the client application or at least outside of the view, because there can always be a situation where the client, or a select from the view, can require a different result ordering, and in that case, the order by within the view is probably an unnecessary performance cost and - in case of an application which orders the data only after receiving the results from Oracle - it is definitely unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

I dont believe you can create a view using order by.  You need to select from the view and then order by in that statement.

Comment: You can, see third line here: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html

Comment: Apologies, didnt see Oracle.

Comment: @user3460414: your link is **not** for the Oracle database.